# How to solve 'coerceValue'-error when using a data-frame?

Tags: r, shiny, dt

```
 shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    DTOutput('x1')
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    x = iris
    output$x1 = renderDT(x, selection = 'none', editable = list(target = 'row', disable = list(columns=c(1,3,4))))

    proxy = dataTableProxy('x1')

    observeEvent(input$x1_cell_edit, {
      info = input$x1_cell_edit
      str(info)
      i = info$row
      j = info$col
      v = info$value
      x[i, j] <<- DT::coerceValue(v, x[i, j])
      replaceData(proxy, x, resetPaging = FALSE)  # important
    })
  }
)
```

I obtain the following warnings:

```
Warning in DT::coerceValue(v, x[i, j]) :
  The data type is not supported: data.frame

Warning: Error in [[: attempt to select less than one element in integerOneIndex
```

How do I make sure coerceValue is editing and saving my new input?

Comment: Use `target = "cell"`, and `j = info$col + 1`.

Comment: target = "cell" worked for me, thank you!

Comment: target = "cell" is correct however j = info$col + 1 is incorrect. Leave it as j = info$col as DT ignores the rownames columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick question: you seem to be using most of the example from [here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html) but not all. Is there a reason for that? You could use the code there, as below, which is simpler:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
        DTOutput('x1')
    ),
    server = function(input, output, session) {
        x = iris
        output$x1 = renderDT(x, selection = 'none', editable = list(target = 'cell', disable = list(columns=c(1,3,4))))

        proxy = dataTableProxy('x1')

        observeEvent(input$x1_cell_edit, {
            info = input$x1_cell_edit
            str(info)
            x <<- editData(x, info)
            replaceData(proxy, x, resetPaging = FALSE)  # important
        })
    }
)
```

PS: target = "cell" as mentioned by [Stéphane Laurent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1100107/st%C3%A9phane-laurent).

Comment: You are right. I am using that website to create a code. 

I'm customizing a little bit so I'm going out of bounds. I'll try to stick to that guide more.